# after decimal why twoo zeros not consider in double

Tags: java, math, decimal

```
private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double input = 300.00;

        System.out.println("double : " + input);

        Double d=Double.valueOf(df.format(input));
       System.out.println("##1::"+d);
       System.out.println("##2 ::"+df.format(input));
       System.out.println("##3 ::"+Double.valueOf(df.format(input)));           
    }
}
```

Output:

```
double : 300.0 
##1::300.0 
##2 ::300.00 
##3 ::300.0
```

Expected output: `300.00`

Comment: //double : 300.0
 //##1::300.0
 //##2 ::300.00
 //##3 ::300.0 //expected output to be 300.00 for double vale(donot want to convert to string)

Comment: What do you mean? In case #2, using the `DecimalFormat`, your value is printed as `300.00`, just as you want it.

Comment: just wan to assign this DecimalFormat value to someother variable Double b its not possible right??
Double.valueOf(df.format(input)

Comment: What's weird about this?  Why do you expect `double` to keep track of the number of decimal zeroes?

Comment: Question is simple when i give 300.00 value to double it returns me 300.0
the result seems to be fraud/manupulated/changed to end user who is getting the response, its related to response of service

Comment: The number of zeroes after the decimal point has no significance whatsoever, though. `double`s aren't stored as arrays of characters, they're compressed into 64 bits. If you want to preserve the zeroes, either use a string instead of a double/float, or keep an extra variable with you that tells you the number of zeroes

Comment: case 1 : A layman gives request of 300.00 to ur service after some deduction (substract 300-250.15) you return 49.85 as response but case 2: same but this time deduction is less (300-200) you return 100.0 Can anybody give better reason so that i can make that person understand there is no chnaged/fraud in values  As they are more worried about the values after deduction in some case have two values incase of two zero there in only one

Comment: @MayankL The average person understands that 100.00 and 100.0 are the same thing. If you really care about the format, you can just pass that `DecimalFormat` object around wherever you're displaying your number. Even better, use a `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2):

You can use BigDecimal for scale and round double. Try this :

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal input = BigDecimal.valueOf(300);

        System.out.println("double 2 digit: " + Test.round(input, 2));
        System.out.println("double 5 digit: " + Test.round(input, 5));
    }

    public static BigDecimal round(BigDecimal bd, int scale) {
        return bd.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
}
```

Output like this :

```
double 2 digit: 300.00
double 5 digit: 300.00000
```